# ActionScript: is an object returned from a function call changed the next time the same function is called?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have an AS3 program that calls a function multiple times. The function must return multiple variables, so I created a class for the function to declare an object containing all of these variables. For example, here's my class:

```
package
{
    public class PER
    {
        public var N1:Number; 
        public var N2:Number; 
        public var a1:Array;  
        public var a2:Array;  
    }
}
```

It contains two numbers and two arrays.

Inside the function, I have the following declaration:

`var newData:PER = new PER();`

Let's say the calling program calls the function, which returns the variables into data_set1 (where data_set1 depends on input variables arg1, arg2, arg3) using:

`var data_set1:PER = function_name(arg1, arg2, arg3);`

The calling program does some stuff, then calls the function again, but returns the variables into a new variable name, data_set2:

`var data_set2:PER = function_name(arg4, arg5, arg6);`

My intention is that data_set1 and data_set2 are different (e.g. not linked together).

My question is, given that arrays are passed by reference, will data_set1 be modified to agree with data_set2 upon the 2nd function call? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, given that arrays are passed by reference, will
>   data_set1 be modified to agree with data_set2 upon the 2nd function
>   call?

No.

Your samples do not appear to use arrays, however it is hard to tell since you don't give us an example of the function you're actually running.

> ```
> Why or why not?
> ```

data_set1 and data_set2 are two completely independent variables with no relation to each other.  You've written no code to make them relate.

Perhaps you meant to ask would the a1 and a2 instance variables of data_set1 and data_set2 be linked.  the answer is possibly.  If you do something like this:

```
var myNewArray : Array = new Array()
data_set1.a1 = myNewArray;
data_set2.a1 = myNewArray;
```

Then a1 for both data_set1 and data_set2 will be pointing at the same array instance.  As such any changes to myNewArray will be reflected in both data_set1.a1 and data_set2.a1 .

Comment: Thanks Flextras, "You've written no code to make them relate." The relation I question is that the function uses the class PER to return the variables. That is, newData.a1 is returned into data_set1.a1, etc. The next function call, newData.a1 is returned into data_set2.a1, etc. (Do you see the parallel in this with the way you've declared myNewArray above?) Is it that newData.a1 is destroyed upon exiting the function the first time that it's no longer possible for the class to link the returned arrays in subsequent calls?

Comment: If "The relation I question is that the function uses the class PER to return the variables." is the root of your question, then let me verify that two instances of a class have absolutely no relation to each other without you writing specific code to somehow relate them. I do not see a parallel between the way I set myNewArray above and the way you are setting the instance variables of your PER instances because you have not shared the code that sets thei instance variables of the PER instances.  What is 'newData'? I think to get a solid answer you're going to have to share your function.

Comment: Thanks Flextras. `NewData` is declared in the function as shown in the question above (e.g. `var NewData:PER = new PER();`). The parallel would be that the same variable (e.g. either myNewArray in your example, or NewData.a1 in mine) is used to set both data_set1.a1 and data_set2.a1. OK, this is probably a dumb newbie question. Just trying to avoid any possible "save by reference" mistakes that could happen. Thanks again.

Comment: @ggkmath I see NewData now, sorry.  However, you did not share the full function.  I don't believe I can offer any more assistance evaluating what your code does w/o you sharing the code you want evaluated.